# How to fetch specific row from the database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm creating simple website and need to get specific column from database.
I need to get only last 5th column from database to be displayed, and I'm stuck here.

This code I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `post` ORDER BY `post_date` LIMIT 4, 5
```

But with this code on my page I get all rows from last 5th column to last 10 and I don't need that I need just to display last inserted 5th column.

My full code looks like this:

```
class Second {
        public function second_post(){
            global $pdo;

            $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `post` ORDER BY `post_date` LIMIT 4, 5');
            $query->execute();

            return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }

        public function fetch_data($pid){
            global $pdo;

            $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `post` ORDER BY `post_date` LIMIT 4, 5');
            $query->BindValue(1,$pid);
            $query->execute();

            return $query->fetch();
        }
    }

$sec = new Second;
    $check = new Second;
    $secs = $sec->second_post();
```

Comment: Please don't confuse rows with columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DESC LIMIT ?`

So code must be for last 8 inserted column's:

`` $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `post` ORDER BY `post_id` DESC LIMIT 8'); ``

This code display last inserted columns from database.

Answer (score 2):

Use `SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY post_date LIMIT 1 OFFSET 4`

The second parameter after LIMIT defines the offset. This way you can return only 1 record and start on record 5 (OFFSET 4).

You can also use `SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY post_date LIMIT 4, 1`, the result will be the same. Notice that the numbers are reversed when you use a comma.

Comment: I try that and that work nice but problem is next i need to get 5th column recent added into database not first 5th colum if you understand me. Explain ( you have 50 columns in database, i need to get last 5th column in this case that will be 45 colum ).

Comment: Note: not from 45 colum to 50 just get 45 colum so in future if i add 10 more columns they will display again 5th colum from database

Comment: You can use `ORDER BY` with `DESC` or `ASC` to sort rows and select the corresponding one using the offset I mentioned. If you want to get the last posts you shoudl use `ORDER BY post_date DESC`.

Comment: Okay ```ORDER BY post_date DESC``` show me last inserted column but not last 5th inserted column.

Comment: Please post the exact sql query you used

Comment: I use now this ```SELECT * FROM `post` ORDER BY `post_date` LIMIT 0, 8``` that show me 0 to 8 column from database but i need to display last 8 columns from database

Comment: If you only want to return the last 8 elements ordered by post date you don't need to define an offset, you can just limit the results to 8. Use `SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY post_date LIMIT 8`

Comment: That display me first 8 columns not last. Columns 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 that code you write me display 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 columns and i need 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 columns to be displayed. I hope you figure now.

Comment: I use now this code ```SELECT * FROM `post` ORDER BY `post_date` DESC LIMIT 8``` but display me example 3,4,5,6,7,8 not 9 and 10 or last 2 rows

Comment: I found solution, code must be ```SELECT * FROM `post` ORDER BY `post_id` DESC LIMIT 8``` what was changed ``` ORDER BY post_id not `post_date``` why my post_date not define in sql i dont know but this works

Comment: I know what you mean, the query I wrote should provide the **last 8 posts** ordered by post date **descending**. Are you sure you want to sort by `post_date` and not by `post_id`?

Comment: Yes, i don't know why my ```post_date``` not define by date but nevermind i get solution, thanks by the way :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: @juniorCoder *"why my post_date not define in sql i dont know but this works"*.... date columns will get you what you expect, unless you have rows with same date or a lower `date` with higher `id` for example `id=9, date='2019-01-02'` and `id=10 date='2019-01-01'`

Answer (score 0):

You can get direct 5th column like

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME -> FROM post;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Query is
`SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY post_date LIMIT 4, 5`

as you want only `1` row, so limit should be `1`.

now you want last inserted so you need to use `DESC`

Just use this query, and you are done,

`SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 1, 5`